# How is it possible to know whether my computer has been infected by a Macro Virus?

Tags: security, libreoffice, malware

Today, I have received a new doc. document and wanted to open it using LibreOffice (Version 5.1.6.2). The following Warning Message was displayed:

> "This document contains macros. Macros may contain viruses. Execution of macros is disabled due to the current macro security setting in Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Security (3 - High). Therefore, some functionality may not be available".

Then, I had no option of preventing myself from opening the document. Although the execution of macros is disabled, I am still worried about the possible presence of the Micro Virus on my Ubuntu (16.04.2 LTS) computer.

How is it possible to know whether my computer has been infected by a Macro Virus?

What should I do if my computer has indeed been infected?

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First thing you could do is run antivirus on the file. With e.g. `clamav` (install via `sudo apt-get clamav`) you could scan a file `clamscan FILE` to see if it is infected in the first place. Can be repeated for the whole file system. - Yet to calm you: the warning regarding macros should not panic you as much as it seems to do now. As it says, macros were disabled and so not run in the first place. This is independent from opening the document (with your security settings).

Comment: What exactly should I type? /home/<File's name> ?

Comment: This depends on where your file is stored. Maybe have a read of this intro to the terminal [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/140679/beginner-geek-how-to-start-using-the-linux-terminal/), especially the `Working With Directories and Files` section. Then `cd` to the right directory and use `clamscan <file name>`.

Comment: I know. This is why I've tried writing it as clamscan <File's name>, clamscan /home/<File's name> and n-even/home <File's name>, with no results...

Comment: Sorry, it sounded like you were new to the CLI. Odd result. It should either give a result report or an error regarding the file not being present. It will nevertheless take some time (20 sec). Maybe be verbose `-v`.

Comment: UPDATE: The Scan in the CLI gave a report with no results and an error regarding the file cannot be accessed... Eventually I scanned the file using ClamTK, and there are no possible threats. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Best if you could write an answer describing what you did and mark it as solved, so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The Scan in the CLI (The Terminal) gave a report with no results and an error regarding the file cannot be accessed... Eventually I scanned the file using ClamTK, and there are no possible threats. Problem Solved.

Comment: The fact an anti-AV says a new file  is clean just means there is a high probability it is clean..

Answer (score 0):

With my angle to see it, LibreOffice is just reminding you that some part of your document is written by macro and it could contain computer virus. If you don't trust the source of this file and it's not necessary to open it, then just delete it. If you really need to open it but you aren't sure that is there virus then I suggest you use some kind of software like KVM or Virtualbox and create a virtual machine for it, if it is virus, the usage of network on virtual machine will kind of like "explode", if this is the case, then only your virtual machine is infected, if it's not, then just open it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I answered the wrong question. If it's harmless, nothing happens. If it harms, you should see something like keep sending enormous amount to a blank IP on your router log or Google locks you down because it's a thing that you should focus now. If the second case has occurred, I'm afraid the only solution is to  reset all computers in your LAN.